# Join multiple tables using SQL & T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Unfortunately, I cannot be sure that the name of my question is correct here.

**Example of initial data:**

```
Table 1           Table 2           Table 3
| ID | Name  |    | ID | Info1 |    | ID | Info2 |
|----|-------|    |----|-------|    |----|-------|
| 1  | Name1 |    | 1  | text1 |    | 1  | text1 |
| 2  | Name2 |    | 1  | text1 |    | 1  | text1 |
| 3  | Name3 |    | 2  | text2 |    | 1  | text1 |
                  | 2  | text2 |    | 2  | text2 |
                                    | 3  | text3 |
```

In my initial data I have relationship between 3 tables by field `ID`.

I need to join `table2` and `table3` to the first table, but if I do sequential join, like `left join table2` and `left join table3`  by `ID` I will get additional records on second join, because there will be several records with one ID after first join.

I need to get records of `table2` and `table3` like a list in each column for ID of first table.

Here an example of **expected result**:

```
 Table 3
|  ID   |   Name    |Info1(Table2)|Info2(Table3)|
|-------|-----------|-------------|-------------|
|  1    |   Name1   |    text1    |    text1    |
|  1    |   Name1   |    text1    |    text1    |
|  1    |   Name1   |    null     |    text1    |
|  2    |   Name2   |    text2    |    text2    |
|  2    |   Name2   |    text2    |    null     |
|  3    |   Name3   |    null     |    text3    |
```

Comment: have you tried `Inner join` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the method I would use, however, the table design you have could probably be improved on; why are Table2 and Table3 separate in the first place?

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int, [Name] varchar(5))
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (ID,
                        [Name])
VALUES(1,'Name1'),
      (2,'Name1'),
      (3,'Name3');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (Id int,Info1 varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table3 (Id int,Info2 varchar(5));

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (Id,
                    Info1)
VALUES(1,'text1'),
      (1,'text1'),
      (2,'text2'),
      (2,'text2');
INSERT INTO dbo.Table3 (Id,
                        Info2)
VALUES(1,'text1'),
      (1,'text1'),
      (1,'text1'),
      (2,'text2'),
      (3,'text3');


WITH T2 AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Info1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN --SELECT NULL as you have no other columns to actually create an order
    FROM Table2),
T3 AS(
    SELECT ID,
           Info2,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM Table3),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I --Assuming you have 10 or less matching items
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N))
SELECT T1.ID,
       T1.[Name],
       T2.info1,
       T3.info2
FROM Table1 T1
     CROSS JOIN Tally T
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T.I = T2.RN
     LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID AND T.I = T3.RN
WHERE T2.ID IS NOT NULL OR T3.ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY T1.ID, T.I;


GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
DROP TABLE dbo.Table3;
```

If you have more than 10 rows, then you could build a "proper" tally table on the fly, or create a physical one. One on the fly is probably going to be a better idea though, as I doubt you're going to have 100's of matching rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fixed, silly me, left the `T.I = T2.RN` out >_< *(after I created the tally table, that was very foolish)*